# Get records between 24th of last month and 23rd of current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know next to nothing about SQL I am trying to make an SQL Query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio where the records are received from within a dynamic period (`24th of last month - 23rd of this month`). Currently I need to edit the dates manually or add them in via an excel VBA macro where the two points in time are declared as two variants. I've been looking around the internet, trying a few things like:

```
WHERE DATEPART(m,day_id)=DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m,-1,getdate()))
AND DATEPART (yyyy,day_id)=DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(m,-1,getdate()))
```

but this doesn't count for 24th-23rd and gives a syntax error.

Here's my code where I need to manually edit dates:

```
SELECT
  reviewer_name,
  CAST(ddd_id AS date) AS day_id,
  report_id,
  report_name,
  amount_events,
  group_name,
  percent_checked_events,
  comment AS SPL_comment
FROM reports_history_GA
WHERE (closed != 1
   AND ddd_id > '2017-01-01'
   AND [percent_checked_events] != '100'
   AND report_name NOT LIKE '%ther_jo%'
   AND report_name NOT LIKE 'QATeam'
   AND comment NOT LIKE '%escal%')
OR    (ddd_id <= '2018-02-23'
   AND check_start_date > '2018-02-23'
   AND comment NOT LIKE '%escal%')
ORDER BY dd_id ASC
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read (and write.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will gives you the dates

```
select  [24th of last month]    = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 23),
        [23rd of current month] = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()),     22)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST('24 '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()),113),8) AS date) AS LastMonth,
CAST('23 '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11),GETDATE(),113),8) AS date) AS CurrentMonth
```

Output:

```
LastMonth   CurrentMonth
2018-02-24  2018-03-23
```

Comment: Changing dates to char and back has a certain 'code smell' about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's alternative to accepted answer:

```
select cast(dateadd(month,-1,dateadd(day,24 - datepart(day,getdate()),getdate())) as date) [24th of previous month],
       cast(dateadd(day,23 - datepart(day,getdate()),getdate()) as date) [23rd of current month]
```